# `git push` behavior differs according to my "login directory" using VSCode Remote SSH

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, git, visual-studio-code, github

I'm using VSCode's Remote SSH utility to access a VM hosted on Google Cloud. My local machine is a Mac.

There, I have a few GitHub repositories I'm working on. I had some issues yesterday and ended up having to mess around with my SSH keys and I think I messed something up.

I logged into my VM directly into one of the directories (i.e. `my_VM:~/foo`). To be clear, I did not log into the home `~` directory and then `cd foo`, I logged directly into `~/foo`. This is a feature VSCode offers on top of simple SSH.

I also believe it's relevant to note that `foo` was cloned yesterday after messing around with my SSH keys.

and tried to `git push`, but was greeted with `Username for 'https://github.com':`, which never happens.

I've searched around and apparently this happens whenever you use `git clone` via HTTP, which is weird since, again, this never happens.

But then what got really weird was when I decided to close the connection and reconnect to another directory `~/bar`. When I tried `git push` there, it worked, no username request.

And then, if I do `cd ../foo` and try `git push` again, it also works!

So, if I connect to `my_VM:~/foo`, `git` doesn't seem to have my credentials stored. But if I connect to `my_VM:~/bar`, it does.

Both `foo` and `bar` show the same output for `git remote show origin`:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/wasabi/foo  # or /bar
  Push  URL: https://github.com/wasabi/foo  # or /bar
  [...]
```

Any idea what this means and how to solve it so that Git remembers my credentials everywhere again? I'm especially concerned since I've cloned a few other repos today and they're all requesting the Username from now on; it seems like only older repos (before messing around with keys yesterday) are working "normally".

Comment: SSH does not offer a way to “log into a directory”. That’s something VS Code does on top. Please confirm that `$HOME` is the same for both connections.

Comment: @DanielB Oh yes, I'm aware this is some VSCode flavor on top. But yes, both connections are to the same `$HOME`. That's how I manage to connect to `~/bar` and then do `cd ../foo` and successfully push.